# how to explicitly reference an operator

Tags: f#

I'm trying to have a go with Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic, and the examples are in C#.

e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firstHeads = Variable.Bernoulli(0.5);
    var secondHeads = Variable.Bernoulli(0.5);
    var bothHeads = firstHeads & secondHeads;
}
```

now there's a bit of magic going on in there, the & operator is resolved by the C# compiler as

```
Variable<bool>.operator &(Variable<bool> a, Variable<bool> b)
```

(actually I even though I've been using C# for over 15 years, I don't actually know how to explicitly reference this operator, I just let the compiler do the hard work...but that's an aside)

I want to do this in F#, so I write

```
let main argv =
    let firstCoinHeads = Variable.Bernoulli 0.5
    let secondCoinHeads = Variable.Bernoulli 0.5
    let bothHeads = firstCoinHeads & secondCoinHeads
    0
```

but this doesnt compile, because the F# compiler "this expression was expected to be a bool" for the subexpressions "firstCoinHeads" and "secondCoinHeads".

thats sort of irritating....so how do I explicitly make F# use the correct operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given answer by @Fyodor Soikin is not wrong, but the proposed solution is unnecessary. There seems to be a bit of confusion about the operators:

- The "bitwise and" is indeed compiled as `op_BitwiseAnd`
- In C#, bitwise and is `&`.
- In F#, bitwise and is `&&&`. **This is the one you want.**
- In F#, `&` is used in match expressions, meaning "and", and as the unary `address-of` operator. **There is no default mapping for this operator.** (if overridden, it becomes `op_Amp`).
- Boolean "and" in F# is `&&`.

You are certainly allowed to redefine `&&&` in F#. To redefine the address-of operator not so much (you get a warning).

However, if a type overloads an operator, F# will simply select that operator if you use the proper matching syntactic operator. In this case, `&&&`. Yes, this is indeed confusing.

If I install `Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic` and `Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compilers`, I can do the following (the `nuget` syntax is available with `--langversion:preview`):

```ml
> #r "nuget: Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic";;
> open Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic;;
[Loading C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\10644\Project.fsproj.fsx]
namespace FSI_0138.Project

> #r "nuget: Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Compiler";;
> open Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.Models;;
[Loading C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\10644\Project.fsproj.fsx]
namespace FSI_0143.Project

>let firstCoinHeads = Variable.Bernoulli 0.5
let secondCoinHeads = Variable.Bernoulli 0.5;;
Binding session to 'C:\Users\Abel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml.probabilistic\0.3.1912.403\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.dll'...
val firstCoinHeads : Variable<bool> = vbool0
val secondCoinHeads : Variable<bool> = vbool1

> let bothHeads = firstCoinHeads &&& secondCoinHeads;;
val bothHeads : Variable<bool> = vbool2
```

As you can see, no need to create "your own" special operator here, just use the actual "bitwise and" operator: `&&&`.

If you run into this again, there's a list of what operator is matched to what method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading. Notably:

[image]

Comment: ah ok, nice, I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

In .NET (and in F#, to a greater extent) operators are compiled to methods named `op_Xyz` where `Xyz` describes the operator itself (for [.NET overloadable operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads)) or the characters included in the operator (for the richer F# operators).

Specifically, the operator `&` is compiled to `op_BitwiseAnd`, and that's how you can access it:

```
let bothHeads = Variable.op_BitwiseAnd(firstCoinHeads, secondCoinHeads)
```

---

The original problem you're experiencing comes from the fact that in F#, operator `&` is "special" (for backward compatibility with Ocaml, one assumes). It's treated specially by the compiler, forcing the arguments to be `bool` and issuing a warning if you try to redefine it. This is a bit of an annoyance, yes, but here we are.

But you could define yourself a different operator as an extension for the `Variable` type:

```
type Variable<'t> with
    static member (&.)(a, b) = Variable<bool>.op_BitwiseAnd(a, b)
```

And then use it like this:

```
let bothHeads = firstCoinHeads &. secondCoinHeads
```

Comment: Operator `&` in C# is `&&&` in F#, which you can just use, no need to create a new dedicated operator. Details below.